# Optimizing the randomPlay Method in a Pylos Game Simulator for Improved Performance

Tags: java, optimization, game-development

I have been working on a Pylos game simulator, and I am looking for ways to optimize the randomPlay method for improved performance. This method plays the Pylos game against an AI opponent, selecting random actions until the game is completed.

Here's the current implementation of the randomPlay method:

```
  public PylosPlayerColor randomPlay(PylosGameIF game, PylosBoard board, Stack<Action5> actionStack, Random random, ArrayList<Action5> actions, int[] locationTable) {

        PylosGameState gameState = pylosGameSimulator.getState();

        while (gameState != PylosGameState.COMPLETED) {
            PylosPlayer player = (pylosGameSimulator.getColor() == this.PLAYER_COLOR) ? this : this.OTHER;

            // Generate list of all available actions for the current player
            generateAllActions(game, board, player, actions, locationTable);

            if (!actions.isEmpty()) {
                // Select random action
                Action5 next = actions.get(random.nextInt(actions.size()));
                next.simulate();
                actionStack.push(next);
            } else {
                // Pass if no actions available
                pylosGameSimulator.pass();
            }
            actions.clear();

            gameState = pylosGameSimulator.getState();
        }

        PylosPlayerColor result = pylosGameSimulator.getWinner();

        // Undo all executed actions to restore the game state
        while (!actionStack.isEmpty()) {
            Action5 action = actionStack.pop();
            action.undo();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea do speed up this method? Every millisecond matters.